# How to push Maven jar files to docker registry?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am naive to docker and i am building a maven project inside a docker image. The application is built and produced a jar file.

```
pipeline {
   agent {
    label 'docker-slave'
  }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
        agent {
            docker {
               image 'maven'
               label 'docker-slave'
               args '-v /root/.m2/settings.xml:/root/.m2/settings.xml'

        }
    }
   steps {
        sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package '
      }
}

        stage('Test') {
          agent {
            docker {
               image 'maven'
               label 'docker-slave'
               args '-v /root/.m2/settings.xml:/root/.m2/settings.xml'
            }
          }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test' 
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can I push this jar file to docker registry (artifactory) using declarative pipeline ?

Also, the above code is not using my settings.xml file. How to resolve that?